# Как вызвать функцию async при нажатии? Python turle

Tags: python, asyncio, turtle

Всем привет! У меня есть вопрос: как при нажатии можно вызвать функцию async?
Вот код:

```py
import turtle as tr
import asyncio as io

flag4 = 1

def b4n():
    global flag4
    flag4 = 0

async def b4():
    global flag4
    if flag4:
        unr.shape(p_right)
        await b4()
    else:
        flag4 = 1
        unr.shape(un_right)
wn = tr.Screen()
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(b4,"l")#Вот строка, в котором я не знаю, как нужно написать
wn.mainloop()
wn.onkeyrelease(b4n,"l")
```

**Обьяснения**
unr(от сокращении - unpressed right) - правая плита(как в игре FNF)
p_right, un_right(от соеращении pressed_right, unpressed right) - костюмы для плиты unr
flag4 - нужен чтобы знать, нажата ли плита

Comment: А что за переменная `unr`?

Comment: @gil9red Я изменил вопрос, теперь можете читать

Comment: использовать 2 маинлупа одновременно это тот ещё праздник)